# Deleting selected records from Kendo grid

Tags: jquery, typescript, kendo-grid

I need to remove selected records from my Kendo grid. However, my code below removes the wrong rows. How would I fix the code, so only the selected records are removed?

```
//Set a reference to the grid
var grid = $("#productionPackageGrid").data("kendoGrid");
var gridDataSource = grid.dataSource.data();

grid.items().filter(":has(:checked)").each(function () {
    var tr = $(this);

    // Current data item
    var dataItem = grid.dataItem(tr);

    // remove rows from grid;
    gridDataSource.remove(dataItem);
    console.log("Removing productID # => " + dataItem.productID + " and Line Number => " + dataItem.lineNumber);
});
```

Comment: What are the wrong rows it removes? A live example would make it easier for others to help

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your tr declaration:

```
var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
```

and this for your data item:

```
var dataItem = this.dataItem(tr);
```